# Convert JPG/GIF image to PNG in PHP?

Tags: php, image, upload, png, exif

> **Possible Duplicate of**
>   [Convert jpg image to gif, png & bmp format using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755781/convert-jpg-image-to-gif-png-bmp-format-using-php)

I have a PHP form that allows image uploads and checks `exif_imagetype();` to make sure an image is valid.

However, I want all formats, PNG, JPG, JPEG, and GIF, to end up being PNG once submitted.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755781/convert-jpg-image-to-gif-png-bmp-format-using-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert jpg image to gif, png & bmp format using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755781/convert-jpg-image-to-gif-png-bmp-format-using-php)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You just need [`imagepng()`](http://php.net/imagepng) then. In fact it almost becomes a one-liner:

```
 imagepng(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filename)), "output.png");
```

You would use `$_FILES["id"]["tmp_name"]` for the filename, and a different output filename obviously. But the image format probing itself would become redundant.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I just changed output.png to "uploads/out.png" to move directories.

Comment: But I'm wondering if this destroyed the temp file? Or do I need to run an `imagedestroy()` to remove the temp file?

Comment: In this example, you can't use [`imagedestroy`](http://php.net/imagedestroy) as it needs a handle (you can get this if you use two lines of code).  The tempfile from the upload will be deleted automatically when the script ends.

Comment: Does Image quality get affected if I convert jpg to png? I know that gif and png supports same color types, but jpg supports more.

Comment: @issueNo329 If your input is JPEG, then it *already has* compression artificats. Converting it to PNG will not worsen those, but won't compress well. (Remember PNGs are for solid-paint graphics, JPEGs for squishy photos.)

Comment: How convert to .ico files?

Comment: @Mostafa: First google result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628114/convert-png-file-to-ico-with-php

Comment: I got this error: ```imagepng() [function.imagepng]: Unable to open 'output.png' for writing```

Comment: @shintaroid Cool. But what are your exact thoughts on "Unable to open ... for writing" ?

Comment: @mario, thanks for your comment. In fact I used ```$file = imagepng(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_FILES["imgToUpload"]["tmp_name"])), "header.png");```, but if I use ```ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, imagepng(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_FILES["imgToUpload"]["tmp_name"])), "header.png"), FTP_BINARY)``` it kind of worked (I still got this error: ```imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: No JPEG support in this PHP build```but I think it's a problem of the server)

Answer (score 16):

Based on what kind of image it is you could select the correct function to open the file:

```
$extension = strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); 
switch ($extension) {
    case 'jpg':
    case 'jpeg':
       $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    break;
    case 'gif':
       $image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
    break;
    case 'png':
       $image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
    break;
}
```

Then you just save the file using:

```
imagepng($image, $new_filename, $quality);
```

It might be worth noting that this will only parse the actual extension and not really validate so the file is in the specific format. For instance, you could take a jpg image and just change the extension to png.
So a better approach is to use the `exif_imagetype()` which will return the type of image not depending on the actual extension.

Comment: How about convert images to .ico files?

Comment: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded error i am getting ( physical path and url ) too.

Comment: @pankajkumar What are you talking about?

Answer (score 5):

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(exif_imagetype($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) ==  IMAGETYPE_GIF) 
    {
        $newpng = 'image.png';
        $png = imagepng(imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']), $newpng);
    }
    elseif(exif_imagetype($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) ==  IMAGETYPE_JPEG) 
    {
        $newpng = 'image.png';
        $png = imagepng(imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']), $newpng);
    }
    else //already png
    {
        $newpng = 'image.png';
    }       
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Very simple using the [gd functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php):

```
switch (exif_imagetype($image)) {
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF :
        $img = imagecreatefromgif($image);
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG :
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
        break;
    default :
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid image type');
}

imagepng($img, $filename);
```

For conciseness this obviously doesn't handle the case if the image is already a PNG.