# Convert animated gif into PNG via PHP

Tags: php, gif

The following is the code I'm using in order to convert the GIF file into a PNG file and save it into a variable:

```
        $art = $_FILES["art"]["name"];
        $art_ext = pathinfo($art, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(strtoupper($art_ext)=="GIF"){
            $art =  imagepng(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_FILES["art"]["tmp_name"])), $art."png");    
        }
        if($art!=""){

        move_uploaded_file($art, "images/".$art );
    }
```

Also, is there a method for converting an animated gif to a static gif?

Comment: Please clarify what your actual question is. The title is not relevant to the question you ask in the body unless you are posting this as a wiki.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work. I assume you are following the example at [Convert JPG/GIF image to PNG in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550015/convert-jpg-gif-image-to-png-in-php) To convert a gif to a static jif you could honestly just rename the png file you created with your current code to jif. All modern web-browsers and applications will treat a static jif and a png the same.

Answer (score 0):

To get the first frame of an animated gif, you can use [`imagecreatefromgif`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php) and to save as a gif, you use [`imagegif`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php), so it would be:

```
$art =  imagegif(imagecreatefromgif($_FILES["art"]["tmp_name"]), $art."gif");
```

Comment: I'm still seeing this as animated

Comment: @pedrumgolriz According to the manual: `When reading animated GIF files into memory, only the first frame is returned in the image resource pointer.`. Are you sure you are not looking at the cached version?

Comment: I'm looking at the file moved into the images folder