# Making a "convert" function in BulletProof's Image Class

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image

[BulletProof](https://github.com/samayo/bulletproof/) is a image-class function that basically makes it easier to upload image files securely. It puts in all security measures which makes it very amazing however there's one slight issue.

I need it to convert all files uploaded to JPEG, but I have no idea how.

```
public function convert($type) {

}
```

This is basically all I got, so in my PHP backend it should work like this.

```
$result = $bulletproof->fileTypes(array("jpeg", "png", "jpg"))
                ->uploadDir("../../data/avatars/")
                ->limitSize(array("min" => 1000, "max" => 300000))
                ->shrink(array("height" => 96, "width" => 96))
                ->upload($_FILES['image_file'], $filename)
                ->convert("jpeg");
```

Of course though, if there is an easier way I'm all ears!

Comment: You are right the class does not have that capility, but thanks to you, I will try to implement it as a feature in `v-2.0` comming soon. But you can can check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8550031/1640606 and http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php and you will see how it can be done. You must also use `covert()` before the upload, because the `upload()` method returns the image path, so it is not possible to method chain. I am in my phone, so I cann't give you much, but if you fail to find an answer let me know, I could try to help a little more.