# Get base64 encoded png image from url in php

Tags: php

I have picture url from Facebook in jpg format. But I can manage it in another code only if it is in base64 encoded png format. I don't want to rewrite entire module.

I have tried everything I found on Internet and nothing works.

The closest I solve this is

```
base64_encode(imagepng(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($url))));
```

If you have some ideas I would like to hear them.

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/imagepng  unless you give it a filename, imagepng OUTPUTS the png data. it does NOT return the image.

Comment: Yes, I found out in documentation. But I don't know how to do it another way. I want something like imagepng but It has to return image which suits base64_encode function.

Comment: so write the png to a file, then base64 encode from that file, or use the output buffering system to capture imagepng's output, and then encode that. you have a lot of options, but NONE of them are going to be possible as a one-liner like you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. get image, file_get_contents('image.jpg');
2. convert to png: [Convert JPG/GIF image to PNG in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550015/convert-jpg-gif-image-to-png-in-php)
3. do base 64: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php