# Deleting the old image after it was converted to png with imagepng

Tags: php

I found [this function on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550015/convert-jpg-gif-image-to-png-in-php) which is :

```
imagepng(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filename)), "output.png");
```

I thought it would fit my needs since it renames/change path/convert to png at the same time, but it doesn't exactly convert the image, it creates a "png copy". I would like the old jpg/gif/jped/png image to be erased aswell.

Is there a way I can add that to this "one-line converting function" ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a lot in one line:

Read the file:

```
$file = file_get_contents($filename);
```

create image object from the contents:

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring($file);
```

create png from image object

```
imagepng($image, "output.png");
```

You should check these steps to find where the issue is.

My guess? You're missing write permissions on the folder you're writing to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your guess was indeed right it was a permissions issues. I actually was able to fix that and was editing my post accordingly to represent the issue I am facing now (instead of creating another subject for the same function) when you posted this :)