# How to get png image from byte Data ?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have below code and i got jpg image. but i want to get png image from byte data.

```
$image_string = 'byte_strng';
$data = base64_decode($image_string);
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JPG/GIF image to PNG in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550015/convert-jpg-gif-image-to-png-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this to get png data

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
```

Answer (score 3):

repalce jpeg to png 
you can change any type by just rename function and type.

```
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php